# How are Scala's traits not really traits?

Tags: scala, traits, mixins

Someone recently told me that Scala's traits aren't "true" traits, and that they were really just mixins. Unfortunately, I didn't get the opportunity to ask him why. Does anyone have an idea what he meant?

**Edit:**
As a definition of "traits," I have been referring to Nathanael Schärli’s [dissertation and concept paper](http://scg.unibe.ch/research/traits) introducing traits. One key feature that seems to be missing from most mixin and/or multiple inheritance implementations is the ability to rename methods when you import them to avoid collision/ambiguity. Can Scala do that?

Comment: Would have to define "trait" vs. "mixin". Ruby "mixins" are not like Scala "traits" in implementation, for instance (I think Ruby "mixins" might be closer to the "true traits" mentioned? Essentially a "stub in the MRO" ;-), which would likely throw off the argument -- terms need better definition :-)

Comment: If we find they are not "true" traits, then somebody better go and update wikipedia. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trait_(computer_science)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt, pst, I've edited my post to clarify.

Comment: For a "true" traits implementation, take a look at Perl's [Moose::Roles](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Moose-1.17/lib/Moose/Manual/Roles.pod) or Javascript's [traits.js](http://howtonode.org/traitsjs). Also, I've proposed a similar [feature for C#](http://codecrafter.blogspot.com/2010/10/roles-in-c.html) (which could be very similar in Java). I've also started [implementing](http://codecrafter.blogspot.com/2011/05/nroles-experiment-with-roles-in-c.html) this vision.

Comment: [Scharli's dissertation](http://scg.unibe.ch/archive/phd/schaerli-phd.pdf#123) mentions and discusses Scala's traits (p.123) as a a «particular interesting» adaptation. The main differences are:
  
  - Scala traits are modeled as abstract classes that do not encapsulate state,
  - Scala traits cannot only be composed but can also be inherited
  - Scala traits support generics
  - Scala traits do not support aliasing and exclusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One key different between mixins and traits is that mixins have fields, whereas traits do not.  Paraphrasing from the original paper, a trait:

- provides methods that implement behavior
- requires methods that parameterize the provided behavior
- do not specify or access any fields
- are symmetrically composed
- can be nested, equivalent to flattened traits

At first glance the third point looks like it is broken in the Scala implementation.  However, traits can only access public fields, which are protected by implicit getters and setters.  The paper goes on to describe that this is acceptable for the implementation of traits.

You point out that a key feature of traits is that methods can be renamed when you import them.  This is not possible given the constraints of the JVM.  A coherent discussion of this can be found here: http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Trait-method-aliasing-td2322026.html, particularly the posts by David Pollak.

Finally, my answer to your general question is "sort of".  To elaborate, whilst Scala traits are not strictly traits as defined by the paper, they are not strictly mixins either.  Either way, it is probably best to use them like they were traits and keep to their design principles.

- Keep them small, with the intent of reusing them.
- Specify behavior not state.

Answer (score 9):

I think that probably has to do with what's in Scala as opposed to what was proposed in the original [paper](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~black/publications/TR_CSE_02-012.pdf).

I once thought about this question too, implementation differences aside, I've come to the conclusion that traits in Scala indeed left something to be desired. The way that Scala let you compose but not exclude methods is strange. To avoid conflicts, it had borrowed something called a **method resolution order** (or **linearization** in Scala-speak) from other languages. There's a problem well-known for languages that support multiple-inheritance, which I will boldly classify Scala as a member of this group. The problem is that it's too complicated and time-consuming to understand.

Scala's method resolution order is a strange beast, it has its own algorithm for method dispatch. It's not Dylan's C3, which is used in Python, with some notable [problems](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=246488), but has all the problems that are associated with it. Worse, I can look up a Python object's MRO by calling its `.mro()` method. There's no equivalent in Scala.

I can tell you I'm not very fond to running the Scala MRO algorithm in my head for every time I need to look up where a method will be resolved to.

Comment: Regarding your last point: a good IDE can help you with this, for example in IDEA hold down Ctrl and click on a method call will jump to the definition of the method.

Comment: Scala's linearisation is well-defined, deterministic and not that hard (later trait wins). Most importantly, it can be resolved statically, that is the compiler can "bind" the used implementation for one class. I am not sure wether excluding methods is a good feature since you are able to break the substitution principle with it; I tend to claim that if you need it, your design is bad. You should avoid having conflicting methods, anyway.

Comment: @Raphael I agree with you. Breaking the substitution principle is probably a bad idea for a language that doesn't rely on duck-typing. For the most part, multiple inheritance in Scala works fine as long as you don't have an overly complex hierarchy, but when you do, just thinking where the methods will resolve to with probably cause some major headaches. All the more reason to discourage bad designs. There really doesn't seem to be a better way to do it in Scala.

Comment: @Wong: Thanks, I think the linearization is exactly what I was getting at. This contradicts the papers I'm reading on traits, which seem to say that a "full" implementation of traits requires some syntax to allow the programmer to resolve such conflicts, rather than being subject to some arbitrary runtime resolution algorithm. In the end, I don't have full control over what method actually gets called.

Comment: @Raphael: Regarding the substitution principle, I don't actually think traits have to conform to that principle. In my mind, that is strictly for multiple inheritance, and indeed is what sets traits apart from inheritance. To borrow from Perl syntax, inheritance has a _isa_ relationship that must conform to Liskov's principle, whereas traits give more of a _does_ relationship, where you are simply importing some functionality, and not necessarily abiding by a behavioral contract.

Comment: @Y.H Wong: If the only consequence a language restriction has is that it discourages bad design, I am all for it. @Neil Traft: But in Scala, traits also perform the role of interfaces, which should (imho) be associated with *is-a*, too. Also, `extends` and `with` do the same (for traits). So I really think that, in Scala, Liskov's should be honored when using traits, and that essentially means (amongst others) avoiding conflicts at all, even though they are neatly resolved.

Comment: You can always write a ScalaDoc, and that will produce the linearization order for each method in the respective docs.

Comment: @Raphael I agree with your feeling about interfaces. I definitely do not think traits should be used as interfaces. That's why I'm coming down on the side of Scala's traits not really being traits.

Comment: Neil, that does not match my opinion. I think you can use traits as interfaces, since I think that even for interfaces you should avoid conflicts. Sure, there is not conflict on language level if you implement the same signature for two interfaces with one method, but those interfaces might formulate different contracts/specifications for the same signature! Such a conflict can not even be detected by the compiler (modulo formal specs) and is therefore the most dangerous kind of error: if you assume Liskov's is honored, you are skrewed -- silently.

Comment: @Daniel Excellent comment! Note that you do not even have to write any doc comments (afaik), the supertype linearisation will always show up.

Answer (score 1):

No, Scala cannot rename on import.

I wonder how that would even work. If method `m` of trait `T` is renamed to `m2` in object `o`, how would `p.m` be resolved if `p` is a parameter of type `T`, and `o` has been passed through it?

Comment: In Squeak, if you rename an import, and none of your other traits have a method with that same signature, then you must reimplement the method yourself. Check out the last example in [this blogpost](http://publius-ovidius.livejournal.com/314737.html) to see a typical use case.

Comment: @Neil Squeak is dynamically typed, so it doesn't really apply to this point, which is a static typing concern.

Comment: Sure, but I would think you'd have a similar requirement in any language that allowed you to rename methods like that.