# Get all fields from anonymous class in Scala

Tags: scala, reflection, anonymous-class

I want to get all fields from class instance through reflection. All works fine for ordinary classes (filter only for example):

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
scala> class A {val a = 1}
scala> currentMirror.classSymbol((newA).getClass).toType.members.filter(_.name.toString == "a")
res12: Iterable[reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol] = SynchronizedOps(value a)
```

But in case of anonymous classes I have different situation:

```
scala> trait B {val b = 2}
scala> currentMirror.classSymbol((new B {}).getClass).toType.members.filter(_.name.toString == "b")
res13: Iterable[reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol] = SynchronizedOps(method b, value b)
```

This value is not public, but method is public. Can somebody explain, what's happening here? Why in case of anonymous class I don't have simple public `value b`? Is there any workaround for uniform members handling?

EDIT

Actually, my original task is to *get all public fields from any instance*. In case of ordinary classes I use this code:

```
val reflectedInstance = currentMirror.reflect(instance)
for {
  member ← reflectedInstance.symbol.toType.members
  if member.isPublic && (!member.isMethod || member.asMethod.isGetter)
} yield //do something
```

Example above describes, why this code is not working in case of anonymous classes. So, now I'm looking for some way, how to get all public fields from both ordinary and anonymous classes.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you're complainig by having `method b` and `value b` for trait instead of single `value b`.

`method b` you're observing is actually abstract setter method for `b` been generated by scalac.
It's not generated if val is defined inside class itself, but only if `val` defined in trait.

Why do they need setter for `val` `b` which is actually `final` (immutable)?
The example below shows how it works. 
Interface and abstract class generated for one trait.
Abstract class using this setter to setup default value but in same time having abstract `b` in the interface allow us to override it in other classes.

```
  class B1 {val b = 2}
  trait B2 {val b = 2}
  class B22 extends B2


// decompile...

public class B1
{
  private final int b = 2;

  public int b() { 
  return this.b;
  }
}



public abstract interface B2
{
  public abstract void com$db$itrac$summit$service$B2$_setter_$b_$eq(int paramInt);

  public abstract int b();
}

public abstract class B2$class
{
  public static void $init$(B2 $this)
  {
    $this.com$db$itrac$summit$service$B2$_setter_$b_$eq(2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I add some more info in my question. Main issue for me right now, is that `value b` is not public.

Comment: @LMnet you've made incorrect assumption. it's public! Your second condition on method verification gives false. The reason is goes from decompiled code I've provided.

Comment: You can check by yourself, that value b is not public. Just add `.filter(_.isPublic)` in my last scala repl example. Implicit setter is public, but value is not, as I said before.

Answer (score 0):

First you can use _.ismethod to filter out methods if you want

From [the scala docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/traits.html): "traits are used to define object types by specifying the signature of the supported methods"

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241219/how-are-scalas-traits-not-really-traits) answer clarifies saying "traits can only access public fields, which are protected by implicit getters and setters". (I believe this is called uniform access)

What this means is that when you are declaring the anonymous class there is an implicit get method for the val (note 'val's do not have setter methods because they are immutable).